# Как создать стиль, обращаясь к вложенному элементу?

Tags: c#, wpf, style, дизайн

Есть такой элемент:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Marka_stpl">
    <TextBlock Text="Марка"/>
    <Button Name="btnCountryFilter" Margin="3,0,0,0" >
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="../icons/filter.png" Width="10" Height="10" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
                        <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,15">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,15">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="ChkResourceAll" FontSize="14" Content="Выбрать всё" IsChecked="True" Foreground="Blue" Checked="ChkResourceAll_Checked" Unchecked="ChkResourceAll_Checked">
                                </CheckBox>

                                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <ListBox x:Name="lstCountries" FontSize="14"  BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{x:Static base:DataCache.CatMetalsAlter}" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=ChkResourceAll,Path=IsChecked,Mode=OneWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Content="{Binding category}" Checked="chkResource_Checked" Unchecked="chkResource_Checked" >

                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.Template>

        </ContextMenu>
    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
</StackPanel>
```

Суть такова, что мне нужно сделать триггер для этой **StackPanel** по имени **Marka_stpl**, что если **CheckBox** по имени **ChkResourceAll**, который вложен в *ContextMenu*, включен (т.е. IsCheked = True), то BackGround панели менялся бы.
То есть поставили галочку задник поменялся, иначе по дефолту. Проблема в том, что к вложенному элементу я не могу обратиться.

Comment: Создайте во `ViewModel` булево поле и забиндите его к свойству `IsChecked` `CheckBox`'a, а для `StackPanel` пропишите триггер с заданием стиля, например.

Comment: пробовал не помогает. У меня этот StackPanel - это HeaderTemplate. Не может он забиндиться почему то